Dual mosfet on resistance confusion
I want to use DMTH45M5SPDW-13 as a load switch. And in the data sheet it say it has on resistance is about 5.5 mOhm. It is a two mosfet package and i want to connect them in DS-SD manner. So if I pass 5A Through this switch, what will I assume the on resistance? Is it 5.5 or 2*5.5 (since they are in series). All i am asking is 5.5mohm is for each individual MOSFETs or it is cumulative resistance?

Not directly related to your question but might be important……Sounds like you want to use these N-channel MOSFETs as a high-side load switch. If that’s the case, you’re gonna need a gate voltage that’s at least 3.5V higher (probably much more at higher currents) than the voltage you want to switch to the load. Some people goof this up so I wanted to mention it just in case you weren’t aware of that.

@steKulov I want to use this as USB power delivery, so the load voltage can be 20V but I can't afford 23.5 volts as gate drive. Better I don't connect that way. What if I ground both these MOSFETs source and drive each gate with the MCU pin?

Are you asking if you can make a low side switch (i.e. switching the ground)? You should probably read this app note. Usually P-channel MOSFETs are used for what you want to do (high-side switching). If you need to use N-channel, you probably need to use something like an ideal diode controller to drive the gate. https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/ideal-diodes-oring-controllers/overview.html

Since the FETs are identical and independent it looks like the specs are per FET and the on resistance of the FETs in series would be 5.5 mohm * 2.
Still, it would be nice if the datasheet would state those things explicitly.
